# wordpress - пропало меню выбора templates

Tags: wordpress

Странно, решил обновить одну страницу, где применяется template, в меню ниже выбора родительской категории, но при заходе в редактирование страницы, этого меню просто нет.
Куда копать ?

Comment: Пишут, что так бывает, если удалить style.css из папки темы.

Comment: Так и есть, но дело в том что у меня файлы css в отдельной папки, может просто сойдет создать пустой style.css ? Или есть решение более актуальное ?

Comment: Он должен быть не пустой, а с заголовками темы.

Comment: Меню темплейт и с пустым появляется видать он просто чекает файл на существование. А не на содержание. Но дело не в этом, просто не хотелось бы иметь лишний "фейковый" файл в теме, не в папке css.

Comment: Лучше не издеваться над wp, чтобы не наступать потом на такие грабли

Comment: Ну почему издеваться, все просто рассортированно, сss, php, js странно что при перемещении файла стилей он так реагирует. Может есть просто способ переписать функцию где он чекает его, типа указать что бы он чекал не по дефауту а в папке сss, типа хука. Ну если нет такого решение придеться просто вынести этот файлик в тему т.е (wp-content/themes/hellotheme/) вместо  (wp-content/themes/hellotheme/css)

Comment: У wp, как и всякой более или менее большой системы, есть свои стандарты. Style.css должен быть в папке темы.

Comment: Ну ладно, я смирился, перенес style.css в тему. Он правда и был в ней, но только в под-папке. Вобщем начал знакомство с ним более глубокое совсем недавно, мне очень нравиться эта система, гибкая. Вспоминаю друпал с ужасом.

Comment: Да, не случайно 25% сайтов в Инете на wp